# Show that there is a number on the form $11 \dots 000 \dots 0$ divisible by 2014

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Show that there is a number on the form $11 \dots 000 \dots 0$ (some number of $1$s followed by $0$s) divisible by $2014$.

I'm helping someone practise for the math olympiad, and this question has me completely stumped. I don't even know how to start. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint.** Consider the remainders when dividing $1$, $11$, $111$, and so forth upto $\underbrace{111\cdots111}_{2015\text{ ones}}$, by $2014$. Apply the pigeonhole principle. Subtract.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Pigeon hole and the fact that the difference of two such numbers of same number of digits is of that form should do it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The prime factorisation of 2014 is $2 \cdot 19 \cdot 53$, so it is enough to show that there is a number of the form 11111...11111 that is divisible by $19 \cdot 53$.

Try to show that for every prime $p\geq 7$, we have that $p$ is a divisior of $$ \frac{10^{p-1}-1}{9} = \underbrace{11111...11111}_p$$

Comment: Carmichael function $$\lambda(19,53)=306$$

Comment: Sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1):

$10$ is an element of the group $\left(\mathbb{Z}_{/19\cdot 53\mathbb{Z}}\right)^*$ whose order equals $18\cdot 52=936$.

Lagrange's theorem for groups hence gives:
$$ 10^{936}\equiv 1\pmod{19\cdot 53} $$
so if we take $936$ ones followed by a zero, we have for sure a multiple of $2014$.